# Is it possible to create key events in android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb

I want to make an app that will trigger tapping some keys.
Right now I was using python script and adb commands to trigger it, for example:

```
adb shell input keyevent 3
adb shell input swipe 100 400 100 2400 100
etc...
```

Is it possible to run it without connecting to the computer ? Directly from the app.
I was trying to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin","input keyevent 3"});
```

but I have no permission (java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied)

Comment: Outside of accessibility services, what you want is not supported, for security reasons.

Comment: So is there any other way to perform some actions on the device? I mean simulation of pressing keys, tab, enter, swipe ? Something similar to 'auto clicker' applications which are available on google play store.

Comment: Presumably those apps have implemented accessibility services, and therefore are at risk of getting banned from the Play Store for not really offering accessibility assistance.

Comment: I see, Thank you.